# AtTask API Converting a Request to a Project

Tags: attask

Is it possible to convert a Request to a Project via the API?  Right now I'm manually creating a project and then updating the Resolving Object ID on the original Issue.  However, I've got a bunch of custom fields that I'm going to have to copy over as well.
Since AtTask has this functionality built-in, I was wondering if there is a way to access that functionality via the API (perhaps through one of the Actions?)
I'm still relatively new to the API, so I'm still learning.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

AtTask's new software release that happened at the beginning of August 2014, added the functionality to convert requests to a project. I would suggest using this new approach to accomplishing what you need.

You just click on issue actions -> convert to project.

There would be a way to convert the request to a project via the api, but the code to write it could be lengthy as there is a lot involved. I am not aware of any automatic api call you could perform to have AtTask's software do this for you.

It would involve mapping each field including the custom fields to the project, then updating the request.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I did not see this ability in the API.  I was hoping to see something under actions.

I was able to do this by including the resolvingObjCode and the resolvingObjID.

Below is an example.

```
JToken projectFromTemplate = client.Create(ObjCode.PROJECT, new { name = onboardingRequestsToken.Value<string>("name"), groupID = userGroupID, templateID = "5468b86c00039ec521cf4042a0cd0419"});

string projectID = projectFromTemplate["data"].Value<string>("ID");

JToken updIssue = client.Update(ObjCode.ISSUE, new { id = onboardingRequestsToken.Value<string>("ID"), resolvingObjCode = "PROJ", resolvingObjID = projectID});
```